# How to iterate over a directory of files and save out to new files with jq and shell scripting?

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm using jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to pull some specific data from some JSON files and convert it to another JSON file eg:

```
cat data1.json | ./jq '[.["messages"][] | {to: .to, from: .from, body: .body, direction: .direction, date_sent: .date_sent }]' > results1.json
```

I have 50 JSON files in a directory to do this to. How do I write a bit of shell script to iterate over all 50 files, perform said function, and save out to 50 scrubbed JSON files?

I'm thinking its something along these lines, but need some guidance:

```
for file in *.json | ./jq | '[.["messages"][] | {to: .to, from: .from, body: .body, direction: .direction, date_sent: .date_sent }]' "$file" "$newfile.json" ; done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jq, so there might be some way to get it to process many files in a single invocation. This will work for invoking it once per file though:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.json; do
    ./jq '[.["messages"...' < "$file" > "$file.scrubbed"
done
```

Using `cat` for redirecting the input to a file is redundant. Just use `<` instead.

If your input files follow a consistent naming scheme like *data**n**.json* and you want the output files to be called e.g. *result**n**.json*, you could use `> "${file/data/result}"` instead (though it might not be portable to some non-Bash shells). Watch out so you don't accidentally overwrite some file whose name doesn't contain "data" though. Search for *${parameter/pattern/string}* in [the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me. And thank you as well for the note about naming the results file as well.